# Ax2012 - get the value of accountNum in the selected row in a grid

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, x++, ax

In the form `cutslistepage` , i want to get the value of accountNum  of the selected row in grid and passe it to another form
i have try that :

```
int64 recordsCount;

    recordsCount = CustTable_ds.recordsMarked().lastIndex();  
  //  CustTable = CustTable_ds.getFirst(1);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to retrieve the `CustTable` record, check the `CustTableListPageInteraction` class. 
In the `selectionChanged` method, it has the following code:

```
custTable = CustTable::findRecId(this.listPage().activeRecord(queryDataSourceStr(CustTableListPage, CustTable)).RecId);
```

This is how you can retrieve the record. But since it is already done, you can simply use the `custTable` variable that is already declared in the class declaration.

Side note: if you have an other form that is opened from the list page, it should automatically be filtered based on the relations between the data sources of the form. So you might be searching for a solution for a problem you shouldn't have. For example create a form that has a data source with a relation to the `CustTable` table on it and it should create a dynaink between the list page and your form, filtering the records for that customer.

Comment: I try this but is not work, he give  the same value info(int642str(custTable.getFieldValue("AccountNum",1)));

Comment: Why are you using the `getFieldValue` method? Just use `info(custTable.AccountNum);`. Also, do not cast the `AccountNum` field from int64 to a string because it is a string, not int64.

Answer (score 2):

If only one record is selected you can do:

```
info(CustTable_ds.accountNum);
```

Otherwise, if more than one record is selected you need to do something like:

```
custTable = CustTable_ds.getFirst(true);
while (custTable)
{
    info(custTable.accountNum);
    custTable = CustTable_ds.getNext();
}
```